# Refreshing PHP file through jQuery in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that takes data from my PHP file and displays it, it shows data correctly but whenever i do changes in my PHP file it does not show it in the extension i have to open localhost and reload PHP file every time to see changes in extension. how can i automate it so that each time user clicks on extension, background script gets reloaded and fetch data from PHP file and display it?

Here is what my code looks like `manifest.json`

```
{
"name": "Amazon extension test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title":"Amazon Product Research Tool",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {"16": "images/get_started16.png"}
    },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<body>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <h1>Amazon product research tool</h1>
    <table id="jsontable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">IMAGE</th>
                <th width="40%">TITLE</th>
                <th width="20%">SALES RANK</th>
                <th width="20%">PRICE</th>
                <th width="10%">ASIN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

`popup.js`

```
var link = chrome.runtime.getURL('amazon.php');
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("success");
      calljson();
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", link, true);
  xhttp.send();

   function calljson(){
$.getJSON("results.json", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.SearchResult.Items, function(key,value){
        var products = '';
        products +='<tr>';
        products +='<td><img src="'+value.Images.Primary.Small.URL+'"></td>';
        products +='<td><a href="'+value.DetailPageURL+'" target="_blank">'+value.ItemInfo.Title.DisplayValue+'</a></td>';
        products +='<td>'+value.BrowseNodeInfo.BrowseNodes[0].SalesRank+'</td>';
        products +='<td>'+value.Offers.Listings[0].Price.DisplayAmount+'</td>';
        products +='<td>'+value.ASIN+'</td>';
        products +='</tr>';
        $("#tablebody").append(products);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Quoting it here just in case. Remove "background" section from manifest.json: it creates a separate hidden background page, which you don't need here, and rename background.js to popup.js. Also remove "background" from "permissions" and add your API URL there. Also use a valid URL in xhttp.open, not a relative path as it's interpreted as a local extension resources. Also right-click inside the popup, click "inspect", and use devtools to debug the code and observe what actually happens.

Comment: @wOxxOm no, I thought i made the last question too much complicated so posted it again with a simple explanation, and i did everything you suggested to me last time but it didn't work out for me. Your explanations are very helpful which i saw on other questions they helped me find bugs in my code and correct them.

Comment: Your new code still has the same mistakes so evidently your actions contradict your words. Well, I certainly can't help if you completely ignore my suggestions.

Comment: @wOxxOm if i removed the background section from the manifest, how do i add other scripts in the manifest?

Comment: There's no need to add them to manifest.json.

Comment: check the edited code above, i can't add my API URL in permissions as it is just a PHP file named amazon.php and it shows an error when i add it in the manifest.js. For xhttp.open i used chrome.runtime.getURL to get a proper URL.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getURL('amazon.php')` won't help you because browsers don't have a built-in PHP engine so fetching this URL is completely useless, it just downloads the source code of amazon.php. The same applies to `$.getJSON("results.json"` - it simply downloads results.json from the extension directory. Like I said, you really need a full web URL for your php page. You will see all of this yourself if you finally follow my advice on using devtools :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to make a function call periodically (in this example every 5 seconds, but you can set it to a bigger period):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() { 
          init(); 
          console.log('initiated'); //remove this, only for debugging
         }, 5000);

    });

    function init() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                console.log("success");
                calljson();
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "amazon.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }


    function callJson() {
        $.getJSON("results.json", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.SearchResult.Items, function (key, value) {
                var products = '';
                products += '<tr>';
                products += '<td><img src="' + value.Images.Primary.Small.URL + '"></td>';
                products += '<td><a href="' + value.DetailPageURL + '" target="_blank">' + value.ItemInfo.Title.DisplayValue + '</a></td>';
                products += '<td>' + value.BrowseNodeInfo.BrowseNodes[0].SalesRank + '</td>';
                products += '<td>' + value.Offers.Listings[0].Price.DisplayAmount + '</td>';
                products += '<td>' + value.ASIN + '</td>';
                products += '</tr>';
                $("#tablebody").append(products);
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I don't want to load it on time interval, i want to reload it when a user opens the extension.